# Symfony remove entity never flushes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

My application has a form to manage user roles. On form submit, when changes in roles are detected user's session record have to be deleted from sessions table:

```
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\UserType', $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user->setRoles($this->setUserRoles($user));

        $changed = $this->checkChanged($em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($user), $request->request->get('app_user_profile'));
        if ($changed) {
//            $sql = "DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sess_id = '".$user->getSessId()."'";
//            $em->getConnection()->exec($sql);
//            $em->getConnection()->commit();

            $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Sessions')->find($user->getSessId());
            if ($entity) {
                $em->remove($entity);
//                $em->flush($entity);
            }
            $user->setSessId(null);
        }
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('users_list');
    }
```

However this code execution leads to exception `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

I commented out code that I have tried with the same result. MySql log file shows 10 sec pause after delete command and I have no idea what it waiting for and why even `$em->getConnection()->commit();` does not work there:

```
2017-08-09T10:02:36.334195Z   217 Connect   user@localhost on mydb using TCP/IP
2017-08-09T10:02:36.336556Z   217 Query SELECT t0.username AS username_1, <...> FROM fos_user t0 WHERE t0.id = 1 LIMIT 1
2017-08-09T10:02:36.373640Z   217 Query DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sess_id = '1gjo6har0vttn7ru63pjrptti4'
2017-08-09T10:03:27.489764Z   216 Query INSERT INTO sessions (sess_id, sess_data <...>
```

Comment: I don't know the reason of your problem but I would suggest you to use a [PdoSessionHandler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html) to store sessions in database and then to implement [EquatableInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) to invalidate session when user's roles change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find out that this strange behavior applies only to currently logged user. So for current user simple logout should be done:

```
if ($user->getId() == $this->getUser()->getId()) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_logout');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- How many session rows have you got in your table ?
- Do you have an index on your sessions.sess_id column ?
- Did you try to run this query with mysql CLI or phpmyadmin ?
- Do you test your code on application used by some real users, if yes
  approximatively how many ?

Please drop your session and user entity code to check relation

Your answers will help me to answering you.

PS: Sorry but I can't write a comment due to my reputation (<50)